# How to create alert for Azure Application Gateway Unhealthy Backend?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-application-gateway

I have tried to use the following options

1. Azure Monitor Alert
2. Powershell Script

Iam trying to test for a application gateway.

I have tried to create alert using the Azure Monitor with the Signal - Unhealthy Host Count for Application Gateway. When i tried to create the alert using this condition, there is a option to select the dimension. Once i select the alert is triggering but it display only the backend pool name and backend setting name, but it does not show what is the error?

Also i tried using powershell script with the following command

```
Get-AzApplicationGatewayBackendHealth -Name "xxx" -ResourceGroupName "xxx" | Select -ExpandProperty BackendAddressPools | Select -ExpandProperty BackendHttpSettingsCollection | Select -ExpandProperty servers | Select-Object -Property "Address", "Health" | Where-Object -Property Health -eq "Unhealthy
```

It gives me a list of unhealthy backend servers but it does not show me the healthprobelog (Type of error).

But when i tried the following Azure CLI command i get the healthprobelog "**az network application-gateway show-backend-health --resource-group xxx --name xxx"**.

Could someone provide the solution to create alert mail for the concerned application team.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of logs alert for unhealthy Host Count for Application Gateway like below.

```c
AzureMetrics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK"
| where ResourceId contains "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS"
| where MetricName == "UnhealthyHostCount" // This metric indicates unhealthy hosts
| summarize UnhealthyHosts = max(Maximum) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), ResourceId
| project TimeGenerated, ResourceId, UnhealthyHosts
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

Here, you can find unhealthy host and create a new alert directly like below.

[image]

You can use with custom log search in signal name create action and details of alert rule

[image]

[image]

Once alert is created any issue occur unhealthy it will trigger an alert on you required time like below:

[image]

***Reference***:

[Azure Monitor metrics for Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-metrics#alert-rules-on-metrics)

Comment: Hi @Imran, I have tried this already but it gives me only the unhealthy host count, it does not say which application gateway and which application shows the unhealthy status. Is there any possibility to check that using KQL query.

Comment: There is no direct queries for unhealthy status in PowerShell and kql it shows only count. you can make use of cli as you mention above. Here is the list all kql queries for your [reference](https://kustoqueries.com/Networking/Application-Gateway/Application-Gateway.pdf)

Comment: Hi @charismaticdevelop I got the solution on PowerShell command using this below cmd you can check the healthprobelog with error details like [this](https://i.imgur.com/t02ZTR1.png)  **az network application-gateway show-backend-health --resource-group "<RGname>" --name "<App gw name>"**

Comment: Hi @Imran, I have above Azure CLI script already with me and you are correct it will give healthprobelog. But i was thinking whether any kql query is used for App Gw Backend Health - Unhealthy status. As you said earlier there is no kql query for that. Currently i have created a powershell script itself to get the healthprobelog. However, thank you for the help

Comment: @Imran - stop posting these "check this" comments (which lead to an image taken from the help pages).